C# Win Forms : Waiting in a loop on the UI with Thread.Sleep does not allow an async Task (not awaited) to execute its code
I am missing an important concept, and I would really appreciate help. I hope I can describe my problem properly, I am new to posting on forums and asking for help.
I have an async task in a Camera class that streams a bitmap from a RTSP stream to a Picture Box in my UI.
I use Safe Fire and Forget when I start the streaming task so I can continue on the UI thread.
I don't want to have await and async all over my form, it became unmanageable and interfered with other threads. The UI is responsive and it works well.
Now, I subscribe to a SnapShotTaken event on the Camera class when I want to take a snapshot. I then call a function on the Camera class to tell it to begin taking the snapshot (by setting a Boolean variable), and then I want the UI thread to wait for the event to be fired on my form.
I am using a loop with Thread.Sleep on the UI which then locks up the UI and the Camera class!
How can I wait for the callback, and let the Camera class continue it's work (which I assumed to be on a background thread since I did not await it) to signal me, without me blocking the Camera class work?
Here is the code to subscribe to the Camera class (ThisFormIPCamera) from a Button Click event
    ThisFormIPCamera.SnaphotTaken += ThisFormIPCamera_RegSnaphotTaken;
    ThisFormIPCamera.TakeSnapshot();

Here is the code of TakeSnapshot in the Camera class which just sets a variable to tell the Camera class
to take the next frame received and send it back to me.
    public void TakeSnapshot()
    {
        _takeSnapshot = true;
    }

The code on the UI to wait which is obviously not good:
    int timeoutCounter = 0;
    while (!RegPhotoTaken)
    {
       try
       {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
       }

       timeoutCounter++;
       if (timeoutCounter > 50)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Timeout", GlobalVars.APP_NAME, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
          break;
       }
   }

This code times out and only with the MessageBox does the code on the Camera class continue and I get my picture.
What can I use that won't allow the UI code to execute, but allow the task on the camera class to run.
Thank you!
I have tried starting using async and await on the functions that contain the calls to subscribe to the event on the Camera class but it became very complicated all over the form and my analog camera gave issues.
I tried to set flags to stop other threads working, but I would like a cleaner solution if possible.

Is the while loop inside an async method? If so, use await Task.Delay(200); instead of the sleep.

Thank you for your reply. It is not. (It was, I took all the async calls out.)

I am wondering if I need to raise the SnaphotTaken event in the TakeSnapshot function, and not just set a a variable which the async streaming task looks at? I don't know if any code in the camera class actually runs after setting the variable;

Either go full Threads or full Tasks. Mixing both will lead to problems.  Its not that easy to exclude certain threads from Task handling. For example Thread.Sleep will put a thread to hold and that thread might be executing multiple tasks at the moment (or more like waiting for multiple IO Operation for those tasks on that thread).

Is the camera class itself a WInforms element?

I can't go full threads since I am using the RTSPClientSharp library from BognadovKirill on GITHub which uses async and then another custom developed component which uses threads and Direct Show to old analog cameras and a video card. I went fully async and it messed up my analog camera component. My Camera class is an extension of his RTSPSnapshotMaker.  I am sorry for the crazy complicated post, I am just completely missing something and so frustrated.  Thank you for trying to help

I have realised that when I try to take a snapshot, I have switched to the ip camera and I need to wait for it to connect and start receiving a frame before it raises the event to the UI , but the UI won't allow it to work, since it moves on into a Thread.Sleep  loop. It is a mess :-(

even though the ConnectAsync to stream to the Pic Box works perfectly in the background. The problem is when I want to grab a frame and wait for it to be returned  to me

Use a Timer instead of a while loop with a sleep.

Thank you! The Timer seems to work!!! I will also try out your sample below with TaskCompletionSource.  I don't know how to upvote your suggestion here.

Instead of a while-loop with a sleep, you could use a TaskCompletionSource, to wait for the snap-shot.
I don't know the API you are using, but this might be giving an idea:
// hold a task completion source
private TaskCompletionSource<MySnapShot> _tcs = null;

// called ones
public void Setup()
{
    ThisFormIPCamera.SnaphotTaken += ThisFormIPCamera_RegSnaphotTaken;
}

// called when there is a snapshot
public void ThisFormIPCamera_RegSnaphotTaken(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if _tcs is null, there is probably something wrong.
    if(_tcs == null)
        return;

    // complete the waiting task completion source
    _tcs.SetResult(ThisFormIPCamera.SnapShotImage);
    
    // reset it.
    _tcs = null;
}

// The method to get a snapshot.
public async Task<MySnapShot> TakeSnapshot()
{
    // instanciate the tcs
    _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MySnapShot>();
    
    // take the snapshot
    ThisFormIPCamera.TakeSnapshot();
    
    //return the task.
    return _tcs.Task;
}

example:
var snapShot = await TakeSnapshot();

NOTE
This code is not able to cancel/timeout or get multiple snapshots simultainously.
